# JavaFX (non-fxml) localization

Tags: java, javafx, localization

I'm learning how to use `ResourceBundle` for localization purposes and I'm currently experimenting with a very small JavaFX application.

This is the code I have so far:

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Button btn = new Button(Localization.labels.getString("s1"));
        root.setCenter(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Localization class:

```
public class Localization
{
public static Locale[] supportedLocales = {
         Locale.FRENCH,
         Locale.GERMAN,
         Locale.ENGLISH
      };

public static ResourceBundle labels = ResourceBundle.getBundle("LabelsBundle", supportedLocales[0]);
}
```

The .properties files are in the same package as the Localization class, but I always get the following exception:

```
Can't find bundle for base name LabelsBundle, locale fr
```

It only works when putting the .properties files in the root folder.
How can I use those files being in a different location? Specifying the path like `"localization/LabelsBundle"` (with "localization" being the package the localization class sits in) doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try putting them in the root folder.

Comment: Oh now that was easy, thank you. But what should I do if I want to use my property files from another directory? Providing the path doesn't seem to work (tried `"localization/LabelsBundle"` with "localization" being the package the Localization class sits in)

Comment: I am not 100% sure, because I have never tried putting them in a different location. Since this question has no answer and is solved. You can restructure this question to address your new concern.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, the question is now edited.